Use of Iana TZ files with Oracle
I am wondering if the TZ files from the website https://www.iana.org/time-zones are compatible with Oracle time zone files? Can they be used to update the TZ entries for an Oracle database?
Currently using the most current release of TZ file I have, but without Oracle support am seeking another source for the latest.

if they're using the IANA db / TZif file format (which is an open standard), then maybe. Don't take my word on it, I'm totally lacking the experience with Oracle - this is just to point you in a maybe helpful direction ;-)
